# Unicorn - 1 process instead of 3?

Tags: ruby, unicorn, vps, gitlab

I am running Gitlab on a 512mb VPS. Gitlab by default uses Unicorn, which by default has 1 Master + 2 workers. These, along with the sidekiq process consume most of the ram on my machine. Is it possible to cut these 3 processes of Unicorn down to 1? (I dont really care about performance here, its just me using it.)

Alternatively is it easy to transition to thin or similar? Or does gitlab optimize their unicorn config extensively?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, within your unicorn configuration file (typically unicorn.rb), you can set `worker_processes` to 1.

Comment: That would still be 2 processes right? 1 master 1 worker? Possible to reduce it to 1?

Comment: I don't think so. One master process, one worker process, that's the minimum I think.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need a minimum of 1 master and 1 worker. Each request will get queued at master until a ready worker pulls it, so the master process isn't resource intensive. Alternatively, you could run GitLab on Thin/Phusion Passenger

Comment: Or you can set the master not to preload, and then it will consume only a copule of hundreds of KBs of RAM